# xslt xml getting first occurrence and merging the tags

Tags: xml, xslt, xml-parsing, xslt-1.0, xslt-grouping

Below is the XML and I am looking for output as below

**Input XML** `(xml version="1.0")`

```
<dynamic>
    <rpc xmlns="http://namespace/example" >
        <route>
            <table>
                <tablename>employee</tablename>
                <count>20</count>
            </table>
            <table>
                <tablename>employee</tablename>
                <count> 21</count>
                <rt> 1</rt>
                <rt> 2</rt>
                <rt> 3</rt>
                <rt> 4</rt>
            </table>
            <table>
                <tablename>dept</tablename>
                <count>20</count>
                <rt> a</rt>
                <rt> b</rt>
                <rt> c</rt>
            </table>
            <table>
                <tablename>dept</tablename>
                <count>44</count>
                <rt> d</rt>
                <rt> e</rt>
                <rt> g</rt>
            </table>
        </route>
    </rpc>
</dynamic>
```

*Please note, only the first `<count>` value needs to be selected*

**Output XML**

```
<dynamic>
    <rpc xmlns="http://namespace/example">
        <route>
            <table>
                <tablename>employee</tablename>
                <count>20</count>
                <rt> 1</rt>
                <rt> 2</rt>
                <rt> 3</rt>
                <rt> 4</rt>
            </table>
            <table>
                <tablename>dept</tablename>
                <count>20</count>
                <rt> a</rt>
                <rt> b</rt>
                <rt> c</rt> 
                <rt> d</rt>
                <rt> e</rt>
                <rt> g</rt>
            </table>
        </route>
    </rpc>
</dynamic>
```

Comment: You should provide the xslt that you have tried to make work and any errors you have encountered

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One option using [muenchian grouping](http://www.jenitennison.com/xslt/grouping/muenchian.html)...

*Edited to handle default namespace.*

**XML**

```
<dynamic>
    <rpc xmlns="http://namespace/example" >
        <route>
            <table>
                <tablename>employee</tablename>
                <count>20</count>
            </table>
            <table>
                <tablename>employee</tablename>
                <count> 21</count>
                <rt> 1</rt>
                <rt> 2</rt>
                <rt> 3</rt>
                <rt> 4</rt>
            </table>
            <table>
                <tablename>dept</tablename>
                <count>20</count>
                <rt> a</rt>
                <rt> b</rt>
                <rt> c</rt>
            </table>
            <table>
                <tablename>dept</tablename>
                <count>44</count>
                <rt> d</rt>
                <rt> e</rt>
                <rt> g</rt>
            </table>
        </route>
    </rpc>
</dynamic>
```

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
  xmlns:rpc="http://namespace/example">
  <xsl:output indent="yes"/>
  <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

  <!--Create a key matching "table" using "tablename" as the key.-->
  <xsl:key name="table-by-name" match="rpc:table" use="rpc:tablename"/>

  <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="rpc:route">
    <xsl:copy>
      <!--Iterate over the first "table" for each key ("tablename").
      The context is now "table".-->
      <xsl:for-each 
        select="rpc:table[count(.|key('table-by-name',rpc:tablename)[1])=1]">
        <xsl:copy>
          <!--apply-templates to the "tablename" and "count" elements. 
          Also apply-templates to "rt" children of items with a key 
          that matches the current "tablename".-->
          <xsl:apply-templates 
            select="rpc:tablename|rpc:count|key('table-by-name',rpc:tablename)/rpc:rt"/>
        </xsl:copy>
      </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**Output**

```
<dynamic>
   <rpc xmlns="http://namespace/example">
      <route>
         <table>
            <tablename>employee</tablename>
            <count>20</count>
            <rt> 1</rt>
            <rt> 2</rt>
            <rt> 3</rt>
            <rt> 4</rt>
         </table>
         <table>
            <tablename>dept</tablename>
            <count>20</count>
            <rt> a</rt>
            <rt> b</rt>
            <rt> c</rt>
            <rt> d</rt>
            <rt> e</rt>
            <rt> g</rt>
         </table>
      </route>
   </rpc>
</dynamic>
```

Comment: If I have a namespace as below and I want it at <rpc> tag and I need rest of the functionality to work as mentioned. how would my code look like
`<dynamic>

      <rpc xmlns="http://namespace/example >

          <route>

             <table>`

Comment: Can you please respond to my edited question on namespace