# How to give generic namespace, if each XMLs contain different URLs

Tags: xml, xslt, xml-parsing, xslt-1.0, xsl-fo

I have XML generating different namespaces, so how can I avoid using name space in xsl and get below result by using one single xsl. Or can I use any wild characters like `http://namesapce//example/*/format`

Input 1:

```
                <dynamic>
                    <rpc xmlns="http://namespace/example/123/format" >
                        <route>
                            <table>
                                <tablename>employee</tablename>
                                <count>20</count>
                            </table>
                            <table>
                                <tablename>employee</tablename>
                                <count> 21</count>
                                <rt> 1</rt>
                                <rt> 2</rt>
                                <rt> 3</rt>
                                <rt> 4</rt>
                            </table>
                            <table>
                                <tablename>dept</tablename>
                                <count>20</count>
                                <rt> a</rt>
                                <rt> b</rt>
                                <rt> c</rt>
                            </table>
                            <table>
                                <tablename>employee</tablename>
                                <count> 21</count>
                                <rt> 5</rt>
                                <rt> 6</rt>
                                <rt> 7</rt>
                                <rt> 8</rt>
                            </table>
                            <table>
                                <tablename>dept</tablename>
                                <count>44</count>
                                <rt> d</rt>
                                <rt> e</rt>
                                <rt> g</rt>
                            </table>
                        </route>
                    </rpc>
                </dynamic>
```

Input 2:

```
<dynamic>
       <rpc xmlns="http://namespace/example/567/format" >
           <route>
            <table>
```

Expected output 1:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
        <dynamic>
            <rpc xmlns="http://namespace/example">
                <route>
                    <table>
                        <tablename>employee</tablename>
                        <count>20</count>
                        <rt> 1</rt>
                        <rt> 2</rt>
                        <rt> 3</rt>
                        <rt> 4</rt>
                        <rt> 5</rt>
                        <rt> 6</rt>
                        <rt> 7</rt>
                        <rt> 8</rt>
                    </table>
                    <table>
                        <tablename>dept</tablename>
                        <count>20</count>
                        <rt> a</rt>
                        <rt> b</rt>
                        <rt> c</rt>
                        <rt> d</rt>
                        <rt> e</rt>
                        <rt> g</rt>
                    </table>
                </route>
            </rpc>
        </dynamic>
```

Output 2 for xml 2 also contains namespace, and this xsl should be capable of handling any type of such XML.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><dynamic>
               <rpc xmlns="http://namespace/example/567/format">
                    <route>
```

Answer (score 1):

Do a 2-phase transformation. Phase 1: standardize the namespaces. Phase 2: do the real transformation work.

That way you minimize the amount of code that has to deal with variant namespaces.

You can normalize namespaces using code such as

```
<xsl:template match="old:*" xmlns:old="(old-namespace)" xmlns:new="(new namespace)">
   <xsl:element name="new:{local-name()">
     <xsl:apply-templates select="@*, node()"/>
   </xsl:element>
</xsl:template>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't use any wildcards in the namespace URI and with XSLT 1.0 you can't use `*` for a prefix.

Maybe `starts-with()` would be enough of a check?

Example...

**XML Input**

```
<dynamic>
    <rpc xmlns="http://namespace/example/123/format" >
        <route>
            <table>
                <tablename>employee</tablename>
                <count>20</count>
            </table>
            <table>
                <tablename>employee</tablename>
                <count> 21</count>
                <rt> 1</rt>
                <rt> 2</rt>
                <rt> 3</rt>
                <rt> 4</rt>
            </table>
            <table>
                <tablename>dept</tablename>
                <count>20</count>
                <rt> a</rt>
                <rt> b</rt>
                <rt> c</rt>
            </table>
            <table>
                <tablename>employee</tablename>
                <count> 21</count>
                <rt> 5</rt>
                <rt> 6</rt>
                <rt> 7</rt>
                <rt> 8</rt>
            </table>
            <table>
                <tablename>dept</tablename>
                <count>44</count>
                <rt> d</rt>
                <rt> e</rt>
                <rt> g</rt>
            </table>
        </route>
    </rpc>
</dynamic>
```

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output indent="yes"/>
  <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

  <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="*[starts-with(namespace-uri(),'http://namespace/example')]">
    <xsl:element name="{local-name()}" namespace="http://namespace/example">
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:element>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**XML Output**

```
<dynamic>
   <rpc xmlns="http://namespace/example">
      <route>
         <table>
            <tablename>employee</tablename>
            <count>20</count>
         </table>
         <table>
            <tablename>employee</tablename>
            <count> 21</count>
            <rt> 1</rt>
            <rt> 2</rt>
            <rt> 3</rt>
            <rt> 4</rt>
         </table>
         <table>
            <tablename>dept</tablename>
            <count>20</count>
            <rt> a</rt>
            <rt> b</rt>
            <rt> c</rt>
         </table>
         <table>
            <tablename>employee</tablename>
            <count> 21</count>
            <rt> 5</rt>
            <rt> 6</rt>
            <rt> 7</rt>
            <rt> 8</rt>
         </table>
         <table>
            <tablename>dept</tablename>
            <count>44</count>
            <rt> d</rt>
            <rt> e</rt>
            <rt> g</rt>
         </table>
      </route>
   </rpc>
</dynamic>
```

Like Michael Kay suggested in his answer, I'd do this transform in two phases. The first phase would be this transform to normalize the namespace. The second transform would be from [my other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47040756/317052) to do the grouping.

You *could* use `local-name()` to make my original transform more generic, but it gets ugly in a hurry and I wouldn't recommend it. Here's an example though so you can make your own decision.

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output indent="yes"/>
  <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

  <xsl:key name="table-by-name" match="*[local-name()='table']" use="*[local-name()='tablename']"/>

  <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="*[starts-with(namespace-uri(),'http://namespace/example')]">
    <xsl:element name="{local-name()}" namespace="http://namespace/example">
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:element>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="*[local-name()='route'][starts-with(namespace-uri(),'http://namespace/example')]"
    priority="1">
    <xsl:element name="{local-name()}" namespace="http://namespace/example">
      <xsl:for-each 
        select="*[local-name()='table'][count(.|key('table-by-name',*[local-name()='tablename'])[1])=1]">
        <xsl:element name="{local-name()}" namespace="http://namespace/example">
          <xsl:apply-templates 
            select="*[local-name()='tablename']|
            *[local-name()='count']|
            key('table-by-name',*[local-name()='tablename'])/*[local-name()='rt']"/>
        </xsl:element>
      </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:element>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Can you comment for my expected output

Comment: Can we use an argument this way <xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:fn="$namespace">

Comment: @ApoorvaBallari - No, sorry. Variables won't work in namespace declarations. What you'd have to do is pre-process the XSLT stylesheet and replace `$namespace` with the actual namespace before processing.